# CH340X issues with programming

Tags: arduino, esp32

I have found a simplified version of popular usb to uart schematic and decided to test it out
[image]

Unfortunately, it doesn't work at least for ESP32, while there is some activity on BOOT (IO0) pin, there is nothing on EN pin (it is consistently on LOW) so my question is, can this be done somehow without additional transistors? And if it's not possible, how to connect transistors to CH340X (the X is important part here, it's not like other CH340 chips)

I should mention this but that is entire schematic, there are no other components between ESP32 and CH340X.

Also, when i cut the lines, connect en directly to 3.3V, manually connect IO0 (boot) to GND during programming it just works, UART works regardless.

Comment: Show the full schematic you're using.

Comment: @Hearth that is literally it, EN is connected to ESP32 EN pin and IO0 is connected to boot IO0, there are no other components between ESP32 and CH340X

Comment: I believe that's your problem. The RTS# signal is negative logic; it's asserting request-to-send whenever it's low. The microcontroller's enable pin is positive logic, and requires a high signal to enable the MCU. Are you sure you *want* the MCU to be enabled by this signal, though? It won't do *anything* when RTS# doesn't enable it--you're essentially making it 100% under control of the equipment sending data to it. That might be what you want, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well, is the TNOW/DTR pin configured as TNOW or DTR?

Comment: @Hearth may be, altho author said it will work https://github.com/openwch/ch34x/tree/main/auto-programmer-solution

What I want is to achieve simple programming via usb using cheap (and small) CH340X 
Normally you need those transistors in order to make it automatic (otherwise you will need to have button on boot pin and press it right before uploading new firmware.)

So essentially I want same behavior as 9001 versions of esp32 dongles

Comment: @Justme CH340X has special section in datasheet about it. Its DTR push pull.

Comment: it should work,  CH340x datasheet here, start at figure 7.9 http://www.wch-ic.com/downloads/file/79.html  picture shows resistor to ground but the text desctibes the above connection as an alternative

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні it should but it does not, i have checked with oscilloscope and reset works as expected, signal gets pulled low but boot does not, I have also tested second configuration - open source DTR but result is the same